# Expected methods do not exists MutableStateFlow<List<T>>() for manipulation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this MutableStateFlow<>() declaration:

```
private val _books = MutableStateFlow<List<Book>>(emptyList())
```

I am trying to append/add results from the database:

```
fun fetchAllBooks(user_id: Long) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dbRepository.getAllUsersBooks(user_id).collect{ books ->
        _books.add() // Does not exist, nor does the 'postValue' method exists
    }
}
```

But, this does not work as I though, non of the expected methods exists.

Comment: Where did you see `add` or `postValue` declared on `MutableStateFlow`? Why do you expect these methods on `_books`?

Comment: @Joffrey, Honestly, nowhere. Except, I saw it in the `MutableLiveData` so, I assumed they both must contain such methods. *I want to append the results from the database to the List<Book> within the MutableStateFlow,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the state of a `MutableStateFlow`, you can set the `value` property:

```kotlin
fun fetchAllBooks(user_id: Long) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dbRepository.getAllUsersBooks(user_id).collect{ books ->
        _books.value = books
    }
}
```

It will trigger events on collectors if the new value is different from the previous one.

But if `getAllUsersBooks` already returns a `Flow<List<Book>>`, you could also simply use it directly instead of updating a state flow.

If you really want a `StateFlow`, you can also use `stateIn`:

```kotlin
fun fetchAllBooks(user_id: Long) = dbRepository.getAllUsersBooks(user_id)
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // likely unnecessary if your DB has its own dispatcher anyway
    .stateIn(viewModelScope)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are actually declaring the immutable list and trying to add and remove data instade of that use mutable list to add or remove data from list like here :-

```
private var _bookState = MutableStateFlow<MutableList<Book>>(mutableListOf())
private var books=_bookState.asStateFlow()
var bookList= books.value
```

and to send the data to the state use this:-

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        _bookState.value.add(BookItem)     


 }
viewModelScope.launch {
            _bookState.value.remove(BookItem)    
}
```

I hope this will work out for you if you have any query pls tell me in comment.

Comment: Modifying a mutable list inside a state flow would be a really bad idea, because the flow wouldn't notify collectors of new values. The whole point of a flow is to get updates.

Comment: @Joffrey Thank you sir for your answer I was thinking that could work but I will admire your answer.